# Animate font size from a div

Tags: jquery

I'm quite new to jQuery, and I can't find out how this works. I want the font size of some text to change on page load. I found the code on W3schools.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var div=$("div");
  div.animate({fontSize:'1em'},"slow");
});
```

And I have the text div like this:

```
<div style="position:absolute;">HELLO</div>
```

Now it works. But the style is in the HTML code, the div has no id or class, and I want this to work on a div which is specified in my external CSS sheet. This div's ID is 'test'. How can I change the jQuery code to work on this div?

Comment: I would not recommend W3Schools as a place to learn, BTW. see http://www.w3fools.com/ for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var div=$("div");
```

to this

```
var div=$("#test");
```

Read up on selectors in the jQuery documentation for more information on selecting DOM elements http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

To `select` a div that has an ID:

`var div=$('#IDOfYourDiv');`

You can also select using classes:

`var allMyDivs=$('.ofThisClass');`

or even combine multiple IDs/classes with a comma:

`var combined=$('#testID, #anotherID, .testClass');`

Check out the [jQuery selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for much more.